# Question about bijective continuous mappings

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact hausdorff topological space and let  $Y$ be a topological space. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be  a bijective continuous mapping . Which of the  statements is true

- $f$ is  a closed map but not necessarily an open map
- $f$ is  an open map but not a necessarily a closed  map
- $f$ is both an open map and a closed map
- $f$ need not be  an open  map or a closed map

**My attempt:** 
Since every compact subspace  of a haudorff space is  closed, my answer  is the first option.

Is it correct? Any hints/solution will be appreciated in case I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `Since every compact subspace  of a haudorff space is  closed, my answer  is the first option.` Yes, but $Y$ need not be Hausdorff. If you do assume that then the first point is indeed true. Otherwise it is the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $X=Y=[0,1]$. On $X$, consider the usual topology; on $Y$, the trivial topology. Finally, let $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is continuous and bijective. However, it is neither an open nor a closed map. Therefore, the correct answer is d).

Comment: thanks u jose  carlos sir  but im not getting how  it is neither open nor closed  as i know that in the trivial topology the  open sets are the empty set and the entire space. can u elaborate more

Comment: Take the set $\left[0,\frac12\right]$. It is a closed subset of $X$, but $f\left(\left[0,\frac12\right]\right)=\left[0,\frac12\right]$, which is **not** a closed subset of $Y$. And $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ is an open subset of $X$, but $f\left(\left[0,\frac12\right)\right)=\left[0,\frac12\right)$, which is not an open subset of $Y$.

Comment: @  jose carlos  thanks u sir

Comment: @jasmine I'm glad I could help.